# why don't tailwind override locally defined style?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack, tailwind-css

I am trying to change the default color of text by a tailwindcss stye. But I cant understood why it's not working. But Bootstrap does override the default style.

I am just new in tailwindcss. Can somebody tell me whats happening here?

[Here you can editd in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-82b4b?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1 class="origintxt text-green-400">{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>


<style scoped>

.origintxt {
  color: black;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly fine. The text is displayed in black as declared by `.origintxt`. You are actually doing the opposite: You are overriding the default tailwind color by black because of low specifitiy. This is by design of tailwind. If you only want the tailwind classes, then dont override style by your own css

Comment: @Marco'Lubber'Wienkoop thanks for your comment. But in general last class always override the previous one. That is not happening here.

Comment: No, the class order does not matter. What matters is the specificity and, if that is the same as in your example, then the last _definition_ of the same attribute wins.

Comment: So, it does not matter if the order is `origintxt text-green-400` or `text-green-400 origintxt`. The result is the same. But the codepen includes the tailwind css _before_ your manual override within the <style> tag. That's why the black wins here

Comment: Try to add another class, say `origintxt2` (no matter in which order). Now declare that new class in your `style` node. let that additional class set the color to red. Now: If you declare that _before_ the origintxt (in the style node) then it's ignored, because the black definition from origintxt will override it. But if you declare it after origintxt then it gets red. Again: the external tailwind.css is  already included in the codepen before you defined origintxt, and because it shares the same specificity as  text-green-400, it overrides it

Comment: Actually the problem came when i tried to add breakpoint. Suppose `origintxt sm:text-green-400`, but it did'nt work. After that i tried without breakpoint, but it gave the same result. So i came here. As say in below, that way worked in this case. I understood your answer. Can you tell me what's the right way to make that ( `origintxt sm:text-green-400` ) work, if i don't override manually by `important: true` in my project?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is with my `tailwind.config.js` file. Just found this during reading the documentation.

By default all css of tailwind generated without `!important`. To enable that you have to add `important: true` in the config file. Then it will override previous class properties.

```
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
  important: true,
}
```

Comment: wooof this feels bad

Comment: @JoshuaWootonn Yes, but it can be useful, and possibly the only feasible solution, when refactoring your front end. Once you are done refactoring all your old legacy styles, this option can be turned back off.

Comment: Bad design from Tailwind imo.

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest to use the [Important modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier) as described in the docs.

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1 class="origintxt !text-green-400">{{ msg }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

In order to use the Important modifier, you need to [enable the JIT mode](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#enabling-jit-mode).

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is to use [layers](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer).

```css
@layer components {
    .origintxt {
        color: black;
    }
}
```