# Tailwind dark mode not overriding style attribute

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have enabled dark mode for my website and it is working fine for the most part. But I have just one strange behavior. A div element has an inner shadow defined in the style attribute. In dark mode, I want this shadow to just disappear. So I wrote this:

```
<div style="border-radius: 16px;
            background: #e9edf0;
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 0px #d1d9e6 inset, -4px -4px 4px 0px #fff inset;"
     class="w-full mx-auto border 
            dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-white dark:shadow-none ">...</div>
```

To make this work I needed to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606861/why-dont-tailwind-override-locally-defined-style) because otherwise, the background attribute in the style tag would overwrite the tailwind class. Then I made some tests and was confused:

If I remove the "dark:" from the shadow-none class it removes the shadow. But if I write "dark:" before the shadow-none class, it will not remove the shadow. Keep in mind that the background changes, even though it is too defined in the style tag and also has the "dark:" tag in front of it. Meaning dark mode is active and all tailwind classes should get the "!important" attribute.

What do I need to change to make it work? Thanks!

(Windows 10, Laravel Framework latest version, Tailwind CSS latest version, Firefox 86.0)

I explain my issue in this [Video](https://youtu.be/VNEcf7Wx4Y4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline style has the highest level of specificity, it won't be overridden by just adding classes to the element.

**Edit**:

My suggestion is to move your inline style to a regular css selector.

**Edit v2**:

As Tailwind docs says:

> ...`dark` variants are only generated for color-related classes, which includes text color, background color, border color, gradients, and placeholder color.

I think `dark:shadow-none` doesn't actually exists (that's why `shadow-none` works, but `dark:shadow-none` don't). If that's true, unluckily, the final answer is that, and giving an alternative will go far away from the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks. What are you suggesting me to do?

Comment: I added the suggestion to the answer, for more info. I encourage you to check out some **specificity** docs, here at [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) or [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Comment: Hey sorry man but I still don't get it to work... I gave the div an ID and then moved the box-shadow to a CSS #id Selector.

Comment: Well, IDs are higher on specificity than classes. That's why your shadow still there (I suppose it does).

Comment: Cool, we are talking about the same, but, as I see in th video, you used an ID `rem_shadow`, and your "remover" is a Tailwind class. An ID is, let's say, more "important" (more priority) than a class, so, the class cannot overridde it.

Comment: but in the video at 1:00 the shadow is being removed by the shadow-none class but the dark tag [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) is blocking the class somehow.